# Is it possible to check if a resource is being watched by an active channel in google calendar api?

Tags: push-notification, google-api, google-calendar-api

We're tracking some resources in google calendar using push notifications api. These channels have finite lifetime, so they expire and there is no way to renew it. I'm setting up a cron to start new channel in case old one had expired. Without knowledge of existing channels, only option is to start a channel every now and then to be sure that given resources are being watched.

Is it possible to check if a resource is being watched by an active channel in google calendar api?

Answer (score 0):

GCal's API doesn't allow you to request that directly, so you'd have to handle that logic.

Here's an example of how you could keep your channels active:

- When creating a channel, include the expiration time and persist that value somewhere
- During your cron task, check if it's beyond the expiration time
- If so, create a new channel
- If not, check if it will expire before the next cron run

  - If so, renew it now

    - Optional: Delete the original watch channel (so no overlaps)
  - If not, continue

Another approach would be to use refresh tokens to ensure API access, without having to worry about whether a channel is expired or not.

- [Google Calendar API overview](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline)
- [Node client example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#handling-refresh-tokens)